# Test :android application restart using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

In my application when the user click on the application home button (android.R.id.home) the entire application should restart. This is the code used for it:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Activity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I need to write testing code for this using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. what I did so far is :

```
        getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
        getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(activity,android.R.id.home, 0);
        activity.finish();
        setActivity(null);
        activity=this.getActivity();
```

But this is not working. I could see the main activity finished but it is not started again since test case is not going to the end. When I searched bit more I got to know, what is happening here is only stopped main activity. If I have opened more activities they may remain without close. The next issue is the main activity not starts back.

So `how to test the application restart when the user click on the home button`? Could anyone help on this matter would be appreciated.